# why would it throw an java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android

This is my main Activity;

```js
package com.example.sendsms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
 public void findContact(View view ){
  
  Intent intent = new Intent(this,ReadContect.class);
  startActivity(intent);
  
 }
 
}
```

```js
package com.example.sendsms;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.example.sendsms.domain.person;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;

public class getContect{
  public static List<person>   getContectInfo(Context context){
   ContentResolver cr =  context.getContentResolver();
   List<person>  persons =  new ArrayList<person>();
   Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts");
   Uri uriData = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data");
   Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, new String[] {"contact_id"} , null, null, null);
   while(cursor.moveToNext()){
    String id = cursor.getString(0);
    if(id != null){
     Cursor  dataCursor = cr.query(uriData, new String[]{"data1","mimetype"}, "raw_contact_id=?", new String [] {id}, null);
     person per = new  person() ;
     while(dataCursor.moveToNext()){
      String data = dataCursor.getString(0);
      String mimetype =dataCursor.getString(1);
      if("vnd.android.cursor.item/name".equals(mimetype)){
       per.setName(data);
      }else if ("vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2".equals(mimetype)){
       per.setNumber(data);
      }
      
     }
     dataCursor.close();
     persons.add(per);
    }
    
    
   }
   cursor.close();
   return persons;
  }
}
```

**I find this Exception throw in the ReadContect with debug,
something wrong with the persons ,it come to null**

```js
package com.example.sendsms;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.sendsms.domain.person;
import com.example.sendsms.getContect;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ReadContect extends Activity {
 private ListView lv;
 private List<person> persons;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_contect);
  
   lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
  
  lv.setAdapter(new ContectAdap());
  persons =  getContect.getContectInfo(this);
  
  
   
  
  
 }
 private class ContectAdap extends BaseAdapter{
  
  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return persons.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   person per =persons.get(arg0);
   View view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.contect_view, null);
   TextView et_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
   TextView et_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
   
   et_name.setText(per.getName());
   et_name.setText(per.getNumber());
   return view;
  }
  
 }

 
}
```

**this is my catlog**

```js
03-28 11:30:52.467: W/dalvikvm(4455): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1d8cb20)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455): Process: com.example.sendsms, PID: 4455
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sendsms/com.example.sendsms.ReadContect}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at com.example.sendsms.ReadContect$ContectAdap.getCount(ReadContect.java:39)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:480)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at com.example.sendsms.ReadContect.onCreate(ReadContect.java:26)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-28 11:30:54.407: E/AndroidRuntime(4455):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

maybe  My expression is not clear enough　，thanks for your Patience;

Comment: According to your trace `private List<person> persons` is `null`. Try to go from there to see why it has not been correctly initialized. That is why is throwing a `NPE` when calling `getCount()`

Comment: I found the persons has been initialized .however it can not return to the readcontact ,is it my way  to use the persons wrong or it cant return this kind of thing?